# Web setup (MSI) project to install in two different AppPool

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-installer, setup-deployment, application-pool

I have a web setup project created with the following structure

- RootNode

  - VirtualApp1
  - VirtualApp2

In the above structure I have the RootNode configured to have the application pool as "RootNode".

I have the VirtualApp1 and VirtualApp2 to be on the other application pool (VirtualApp).
On Installing the MSI, we  choose the installation address as the RootNode but we can choose only one of the application pool listed. Is it possible to have MSI to install for two different application pool under the same roof.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what tool you are using to build the package. Advanced Installer (Professional edition) can do this very easily, when [creating an installer for IIS applications](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html).

In the IIS page you can define the App Pools, web sites, web applications and virtual directories you want your installer to create, as shown in the above linked tutorial. For each web site and virtual application you can then select from itw own "Application Pool" view the corresponding application pool. Virtual directories do not support having different application pools from their parents.